# why am i getting a index is out of range error

Tags: python, tkinter, pytube

```
from tkinter import *
import pytube
import threading

def download():
    link = test_url.get()

    yt = pytube.YouTube(link)
    videos = yt.get_videos()

    n = quality.get()

    vid = videos[n - 1]

    destination = destination_test.get()
    vid.download(destination)

def test():
    threading.Thread(target=download()).start()

root = Tk()
test_url = StringVar()
quality = IntVar()
destination_test = StringVar()
url_label = Label(text='Enter Url')
quality_label = Label(text='quality')
url_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
quality_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
destination_label = Label(text='Destination')
destination_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
url_entry = Entry(textvariable=test_url)
url_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

quality_entry = Entry(textvariable=quality)
quality_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
destination_entry = Entry(textvariable=destination_test)
destination_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)
download_button = Button(text='download', command=test())
download_button.grid(row=3, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
> >     2017.1.4\helpers\pycharm_jb_unittest_runner.py", line 35, in 
> >         main(argv=args, module=None, testRunner=unittestpy.TeamcityTestRunner, buffer=not
> >     JB_DISABLE_BUFFERING)   File "C:\Python36\lib\unittest\main.py", line
> >     93, in **init**
> >         self.parseArgs(argv)   File "C:\Python36\lib\unittest\main.py", line 140, in parseArgs
> >         self.createTests()   File "C:\Python36\lib\unittest\main.py", line 147, in createTests
> >         self.module)   File "C:\Python36\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 219, in loadTestsFromNames
> >         suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]   File "C:\Python36\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 219, in 
> >         suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]   File "C:\Python36\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 153, in
> >     loadTestsFromName
> >         module = **import**(module_name)   File "C:\Users\Matthew\PycharmProjects\test\test.py", line 37, in 
> >         download_button = Button(text='download', command=test())   File "C:\Users\Matthew\PycharmProjects\test\test.py", line 19, in test
> >         threading.Thread(target=download()).start()   File "C:\Users\Matthew\PycharmProjects\test\test.py", line 13, in download
> >         vid = videos[n - 1] IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Please add an explanation of how this came to be. Also, please add a [mcve].

Comment: The problem came to be after I tried to tread the video so the GUI window would not freeze.

Answer (score 2):

Because the value of your variable 'n' either equals to 0, or it's larger than your number of videos by 2 or more.

Whatever quality.get() does, whatever quality variable is, `n=quality.get()` is the line that eventually causes error...

Comment: or making sure to check `len(videos)` before trying an index

Comment: I just want to stop the window from freezing while downloading